# How can I reuse a JavaScript function for different buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

I want to use one javascript function which can hide or show different divs (none/block). But for every different button clicked, a different div should show or hide.

My function is as follows:

```
function visibility() {
    var x = document.getElementById("searchfield");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

And the buttons are:

```
<div><button id="subclass_button" onclick="visibility()">Age</button>
      <div><button id="subclass_button" onclick="visibility()">Death Place</button>
      <div><button id="subclass_button" onclick="visibility()">Death Cause</button>
      <div><button id="subclass_button" onclick="visibility()">Music Genre</button>
      <div><button id="subclass_button" onclick="visibility()">Gender</button>
      <div><button id="subclass_button" onclick="visibility()">Birthplace</button>
```

The divs I want to show/hide are like these and must be linked to one button:

```
<div id="gender">
        <button>Male</button>
        <button>Female</button>
      </div>

      <div id="deathPlace">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for a death place..." >
        <button ng-click="doMyAction()" type="button">Search</button>
      </div>

      <div id="birthplace">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for a birthplace..." >
        <button ng-click="doMyAction()" type="button">Search</button>
      </div>
```

So if I press the gender button, I only want the div with id="gender" to show up.
I hope some one can help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Java is not short for JavaScript.

Comment: pass your div id in function like `onclick="visibility('divid')"`

Comment: Well you need to add logic to know what is supposed to be toggled. Pass in an id, use that id to toggle.

Comment: @epascarello what error?

Comment: in your visibiity function `this` will be the element you're trying to interact with

Comment: `id`'s are for identification not for classification. They have to be unique. Use `class` instead.

Comment: @ArunKumar You should separate the application logic from the event handler. In addition, attaching the event handler to the element should happen in the JavaScript code instead of hardcoding it into the HTML. (See *Maintainable JavaScript* by Nicholas Zakas.)

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Application logic is already separated and if we have fixed/hardcoded elements then we can use this kind of approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just send an id of the target div to your function

```
<div><button id="subclass_button" onclick="visibility('gender')">Gender</button>
```

then in your function

```
function visibility(divId) {
  var x = document.getElementById(divId);
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```